# How to port from GNU MP (libgmp) mpz_t to System.Numerics.BigInteger (.NET)

Tags: c#, c, type-conversion, biginteger, gmp

I've been trying to port a C application using GNU MP (libgmp) to C#, using the `BigInteger` type in `System.Numerics`. The application makes a lot of type conversions between the big integer type `mpz_t` and byte arrays (`uint8_t` or `char`) or `uint32_t` arrays. I would like to maintain these conversions and end up with a port as close to the original as possible which also remains compatible.
I've been fiddling with it for a few hours, but somehow [it doesn't come out right](https://github.com/dorianmuthig/SSSsharp/blob/master/SSSsharp/Program.cs). Could someone point out what I am doing wrong and/or tell me how to correctly deal with `System.Numerics.BigInteger` in a way that is compatible with the `mpz_import` and `mpz_export` methods libgmp provides?
I found out yesterday, that bit shifting `BigInteger`s [is messed up](https://twitter.com/dorianmuthig/status/582658572305199104). Maybe it's not the only thing. If there is a bug in the framework, and you'd tell me, I suppose that's helpful, too. :)

Comment: So what is actually wrong with your code? Did you debug it? Does it compile? Does it crash? Does it output an error? Which is the line which causes the undesired behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure, yet. Yes. Yes. No. No, well... not an unhandled one. It's more of a mystery problem at this point, and may not actually be my doing, but incorrect documentation, something which annoys me greatly...

Comment: So again, what should I be looking for when reading that code and at which lines?

Comment: I can imagine the `mpz_setbit` method doesn't do the same as the method at line #809, I can also imagine `mpz_import` doesn't do the same as the method at line #961 or `mpz_export` not doing the same as the method at line #907. I can also imagine through some weird bug in the framework, that the methods at lines #873 and #869 don't do the same as `mpz_xor` and `mpz_mul_2exp` respectively. I can also imagine, that I mucked up the `field_import` method at line #441 (see comment) but I'm more doubtful there than with anything else. It's also possible the method at line #853 is wrong, but unlikely

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that what you're asking here is "here's a bunch of code. Please debug it and figure out what is wrong with it", without providing some clear unit tests that prove clearly the faulty behaviour. I will not do that work for you. At this stage, I'd suggest that you pick the "suspicious" methods and write some unit tests for them, which might reveal the "unexpected" behaviour. That will help us see clearly which code misbehaves and we might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Also, it seems that you are sometimes reinventing the wheel. For example, what's the point of the Xor method when there already exists [BigInteger.ExclusiveOr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.op_exclusiveor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: It behaves as I expect, considering the code "I wrote". However, the whole thing does not behave in the same way as the C code. I do not care if you do any work for me or not. Any work you do may very well be redundant to what I am doing already anyway. Asking for help does however improve my odds of figuring out where the problem is faster, even if those odds may be miniscule.
Unit tests are pointless here, because of influence from cryptographic pseudo-randomness _or_ because such tests would be code that is potentially subject to the same issues in the framework binary and thus unreliable

Comment: The point of the `<BigInteger>.Xor` extension method is a bug in the `BigInteger` XOR operand method not consistently flipping the bits correctly, even for small numbers. I believe there is a comment next to it that says so. Might be missing in the version I posted. Also, and I haven't looked into why, but my method appears faster, too. This may however be a result of the `System.Numerics` binary being compiled with older tools common from when .NET 4.0 was new and this being a 4.5.2 project.

I am not really looking for anyone to fix my code for me. I'd prefer knowing about strange "gotchas".

Comment: Have you considered doing some boundary value analysis for your functions and some randomized value testing? My understanding is that *your code* is not working properly. Just take a snapshot of all the random values when it misbehaves and inject them through a unit test in a mock RNG. This will yield a test that will consistently produce the erroneous behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that now. I'm testing my code (and that of `System.Numerics.BigInteger`) against that of libgmp. Again, unit tests are not useful in this scenario. At least, though it may be sort of what I am doing, not the conventional automated kind. This is not an application where the testing of a function that causes me grief can be verified against expected output in a reliable way without effectively reproducing that same functionality. That would be very redundant.